# Rails 4 image_path('image.jpg') displays image path instead of actual image.

Tags: image, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

Running Rails 4 and deployed to Heroku and have been struggling with a strange issue.

Config contains:

```
 config.assets.compile = true
```

Gemfile contains:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Have a line in my application.html.erb to render an image:

```
<%= image_path('image.jpg') %>
```

Placed my image in the following locations (excessive but troubleshooting):

```
assets
assets/images
public
public/images
```

I am compiling assets during my deployment to Heroku (slug compilation) and no errors are returned.

When I open the webpage the image is not rendered and instead the path is provided as:

```
 "/images/image.jpg"
```

Any thoughts as to why this is occurring?

Thank you all in advanced

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour for `image_path`.  I think what you're looking for is `image_tag`.

For example, if your image is `assets/images/image.png` to render it in the view you would use:

`<%= image_tag('image.png') %>`

That is the recommended method, but you could also do

`<img src="<%= image_path('image.png')%>" />`